# Multiple radio buttons ajax post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I'm new in web programming and I really need your help. I have a form with several radio buttons and I want to insert them into mysql through an ajax post. I can do it for a single button but for more than one I don't have idea how to do it.

This is a part of my html and jquery:

```
<html>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                var q1 = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
                if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == "0") {
                    alert("Select any value");
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax-check.php",
                        data: "q1=" + q1,
                        success: function () {
                            $("#msg").addClass('bg');
                            $("#msg").html("value Entered");
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="msg"></div>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <div class="Clear">
                question1:bla bla bla
                <input class="star required" type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q1" value="2" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q1" value="3" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q1" value="4" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q1" value="5" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="Clear">
                question2:bla bla bla
                <input class="star required" type="radio" name="q2" value="1" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q2" value="2" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q2" value="3" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q2" value="4" />
                <input class="star" type="radio" name="q2" value="5" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is how I insert the button in mysql:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db('db', $query);

if (isset($_POST['q1'])) {
    $choice1 = $_POST['q1'];
    $choice2 = $_POST['q2'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb VALUES('','$choice1')");
}
?>
```

I've tried to make a var for each button but dosen't worked.
How could I post all values in php and what should I change into my ajax and php?
Thanks!

This is how I did the .php

```
<?php
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('cosmote',$query);
$q = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
  $q[$i] = isset($_POST['q'+$i]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['q'+$i]) : 0;
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabel (q1,q2) VALUES ('$q[1]','$q[2]')");
?>
```

Comment: The way you format your code is atrocious. I'm sorry but that's the truth. You make it unnecessarily harder to read for yourself and others as well. Code is written once but read many times so great care should be taken to make it beautiful. I'll post what it should look like in a later comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but now I am learning, thanks a lot for your advices and for trying to help me. I'll wait anxious for your comment. You're great!

Comment: This is how the HTML and JavaScript should have been formatted: http://pastebin.com/fZt7sUcY

Comment: And the PHP (it wasn't as bad as the other): http://pastebin.com/ZhtxwCf1

Comment: You' re right, is much easier to read it now and to detect eventually errors. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I formatted your question too.

Comment: Please can you help me in this problem. I'm really stucked, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Now I'm busy with something else but I'll look into it later (in at most 20 minutes).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! You're so kind, I rarely met people like you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19726/discussion-between-user1820705-and-botond-balazs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here is how to do it. First, add an `id` to the form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
```

This will make it easier to access via jQuery. Then, pass the serialized form as the POST data to your PHP script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {                
        if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length == "0") {
            alert("Select any value");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax-check.php",
                data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $("#msg").addClass('bg');
                    $("#msg").html("value Entered");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

After that, you can get the radio button values from the `$_POST` array in your PHP script:

```
$_POST['q1'] // value of q1, can be 1-5
$_POST['q2'] // value of q1, can be 1-5
```

**EDIT:** The problem with your PHP code is that you used `+` instead of `.` for concatenating strings. Write this instead:

```
$q[$i] = isset($_POST['q'.$i]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['q'.$i]) : 0;
```

After this, I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: I saw your edit that was removed later (add it to the question instead of my answer). Don't let the beginner mistakes discourage you. Once you get the hang of it, programming will be a lot of fun.

Comment: OK, i'll add it right now, thanks for encourage me, I appreciate.

Comment: I've just added the solution to my answer.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, you're really good. You saved me! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form, it will give you the values of the form as if you was submitting it regularly `data: $('form').serialize(),`